# How can I delete all transitions in MS Powerpoint with VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

We prepare hundreds of Powerpoint documents per week for use with screen-reading software and need to remove all animations and transitions from each one. I'd like to write a Powerpoint add-in that automatically does this when the file is loaded. I've figured out how to delete all animations using the following code in an `auto_open()` sub which I've imported as an add-in:

```
'Loop Through Each Slide in ActivePresentation
  For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides

    'Loop through each animation on slide
      For x = sld.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count To 1 Step -1

        'Remove Each Animation
          sld.TimeLine.MainSequence.Item(x).Delete           

      Next x

  Next sld
```

However, I'm not sure how to delete transitions with this method. I've essentially solved the problem *visually* by adding in this line,

```
sld.SlideShowTransition.Duration = 0
```

but I'd like to outright delete the transitions as they interfere with clients' screen-reading software. Deleting the object in the paradigmatic VBA way (`SlideShowTransition.Delete`) doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This'll do it:

```
sld.SlideShowTransition.EntryEffect=0
```